# Qual uma boa tradução para o Inglês de "eu quero nascer" na música de Cartola?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Na música `Preciso me Encontrar` de Cartola, qual seria uma boa tradução da sentença "Eu quero nascer" quando ele canta "Eu quero nascer, quero viver"?

"I want to be born" parece muito estranho - qual seria uma boa tradução que não fuja totalmente do contexto da sentença?

EDIT: Adicionando o trecho da música onde a sentença é utilizada:

> Quero assistir ao sol nascer
>
> Ver as águas dos rios correr
>
> Ouvir os pássaros cantar
>
> Eu quero nascer
>
> Quero viver

Comment: Talvez "I want to reborn"?

Comment: sugestão: colocar a estança da música que contém a frase “eu quero nascer”. Talvez ajude a dar contexto.

Comment: É, definitivamente precisa do contexto.

Comment: "reborn" não é um verbo no infinitivo, portanto não podemos dizer "to reborn".  Reborn é um particípio passado ou um adjetivo.  Poderias dizer "I want to be reborn" ou  "I feel reborn after a few weeks vacationing.

Comment: Obrigado. Eu adicionei o trecho da música onde a sentença é utilizada no OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lendo a letra da música, eu traduziria como "I want to be reborn and live "  ou "I want to feel reborn and really live".

Comment: Gostei do "I want to feel reborn", soa melhor em Inglês. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Eu simplesmente traduziria como:

> I want to be born
> I want to live